# Xamarin.Forms: ListView inside StackLayout: How to set height?

Tags: xamarin.forms

In a `ContentPage` I have a `ListView` inside a `StackLayout` inside a `ScrollView`. The `ListView` is populated (`ItemSource` is set) in the `ContentPage` when `OnAppearing` gets called and I can see that the list is populated in the emulator. The `StackLayout`s orientation is `Vertical` and below the `ListView` I have a `Button`.

My problem is that no matter how many elements the `ListView` has, it gets the height of 53.33. I would like the height of the `ListView` to match the total height of the items in it. By setting `HeightRequest` I can set the height of the `ListView` to anything I want, but since I do not know the height of the items inside the `ListView` the result is most often that the distance to the button below it is incorrect and therefore looks ugly. I have tried to set `VerticalOptions` on both the `ListView` and the `StackLayout` to `Start`and other settings, but this does not change the height from 53.33 (and if I try to combine using `HeightRequest` and `Start` it turns out that HeightRequest wins out).

How can I solve this?

(please excuse the cross posting from [Xamarin forum](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/19874/listview-inside-stacklayout-a-height-problem))

Comment: someone help me for this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58329028/xamarin-forms-listview-size-to-content

Comment: someone help me for this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58329028/xamarin-forms-listview-size-to-content

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The solution in my case was to put the `ListView` inside a `StackLayout` and then put that `StackLayout` inside the main `StackLayout`. Then I could set the `VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand` on the inner `StackLayout` (the one containing the `ListView`) with the result that the `ListView` got the space it needed (which of course varies depending on the data).

Here is the main code:

```cs
listView.ItemsSource = alternativeCells;
listView.ItemSelected += ListViewOnItemSelected;
var listStackLayout = new StackLayout
{
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
    Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical
};
listStackLayout.Children.Add(listView);
_stackLayout.Children.Add(listStackLayout);
```

As you see, I added a new `StackLayout` with the only purpose of putting the `ListView` inside it.  Then I put that `listStackLayout` inside the main `_stackLayout`.

See the post on [this Xamarin forum post](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/66248) for more information

Comment: I cannot recreate your solution. could you be more specific? (for example, say options of other elements, like parent stacklayout)

Comment: @NikaGamkrelidze Unfortunately I do not have access to the code any longer. Sorry!

Comment: I ran into the same problem but your soultion did not help me. I can't believe this problem is around for 3 years and they still have not fixed it. My ListView always uses more space than it would need to display the items.

Answer (score 25):

With the new `BindableLayout` feature in Xamarin Forms 3.5 you can easily use the `ItemsSource` on `StackPanel`.

So, basically you can write something like this:

```
<StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding list}">
    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            ...
        </DataTemplate>
    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
</StackLayout>
```

You can read more about it here: https://blog.xamarin.com/xamarin-forms-3-5-a-little-bindable-love/

Comment: Effing brilliant! How did I miss this??? The ability to bind to a StackLayout is awesome. I'm using it in a place where I need to provide a small preview list of a larger list that will be presented in its own proper detail view. Binding to a StackLayout saved me all the headaches associated with getting a ListView to size appropriately and disable scrolling & tap highlighting, etc. Very cool.

Comment: Loved this! Use this and forget about all the problems to deal with ListViews.

Comment: FYI, the BindableLayout performance is poor. Noticeably slower than ListView when ItemSource exceeds 15-20 items.

Comment: @lestersconyers I think BindableLayout is not the option when the performance matters. In the situations which performance is important, the items are too many, so a solution with virtualization should be selected, like ListView or ... The BindableLayout best fits for situations with few and limited items.

Comment: But this way you cannot bind the selected Item can you ?

Answer (score 18):

I ran into the same problem, and for me this worked like a charm:

```
listView.HasUnevenRows = true;
```

(http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/listview/#Display_Rows_with_Variable_Heights)

Comment: This fixed my issue, where list had only one row at the begining and after adding rows, list would not resize to take all available height.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem, and this was the only thing I did that solved for me (in XAML):

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"
             VerticalOptions="Fill"
             HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
    <ListView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
              RowHeight="<some row height>">
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

Hope it works!

Answer (score 8):

Below code worked for me,

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
base.OnAppearing(); 
listViewOrderCloths.HeightRequest = model.ListOrderedCloths.Count*100)/2 ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar struggle, with a slightly different solution.  First, setting a RowHeight on the ListView seemed to be pivotal.  Second, I was running into a binding + timing issue.  If the ListView was displayed and had no contents, it was set to a default height (showing the empty space).  If I moved away from this page and came back, the size was fine.

So my approach was to bind the ListView's visibility to the presence (or lack of) something being bound to.  Then when data came back, the ListView became visible and had the proper size.

```
<ListView x:Name="lvSettlements" ItemsSource="{Binding RecentSettlements}"  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" RowHeight="25" IsVisible="{Binding RecentSettlements, Converter={StaticResource nullConverter}}">
...SNIP...
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

On Android, my table created in code was leaving gaps above and below it.

This fixed it...

```
HeightRequest="1000000"
```

I think I have the hackiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer wasn't applicable to my situation, where my `ListView` might be longer then the length of the display, hence it needs be placed within a `ScrollView`, which brings back the empty space.

They way I solved this, was to have top level `StackLayout` and then place the `ListView` in an immediate `ScrollView`, like the following XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<local:ContentPage>
    <StackLayout x:Name="entirePage">
        <ScrollView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            Orientation="Vertical">
            <ListView x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                Margin="0">
                <!-- ListView Stuff -->
            </ListView>
        </ScrollView>
    </StackLayout><!--entirePage-->
</local:ContentPage >
```